# Автозаполнение родителя элементами

Tags: html, css

Имеется родитель фиксированной ширины, как сделать так, чтобы дети, сколько бы их ни было автоматически заполняли всю ширину родителя, т.е. делили ширину родителя между собой поровну. Например у нас есть родитель и в нем 4 элемента, нужно чтобы все элементы стали по 25%, добавляем один элемент, все элементы становятся уже по 20% в ширину и так далее.

```css
.main-block {
  width: 800px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
}

.items {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 18%;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  margin: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-block">
  <div class="items">item1</div>
  <div class="items">itemitem2</div>
  <div class="items">item3</div>
  <div class="items">itemitem4</div>
  <div class="items">item</div>
</div>
```

Есть ли решение без использования JavaScrip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ознакомьтесь с свойством flex-grow

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 100px auto 0px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.block__item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.block__item:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__item">1</div>
  <div class="block__item">2</div>
  <div class="block__item">3</div>
  <div class="block__item">4</div>
  <div class="block__item">5</div>
  <div class="block__item">6</div>
</div>
```